# Vuetify Material Icons are showing are text sometimes

Tags: vuetify.js

I am using both Material Icons and Font Awesome icons in my vuejs app.

Sometimes, these material icons are showing as plain text in both Firefox and Chrome. This is only happening once in a while.
I found out two issues in console and network tab of my browser.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U679B.jpg)
I have installed font-awesome and material-icons as dependencies. Due to my deployment process, I have those (ttf, woff and eot) files locally in my dist folder as static assets.

Please help!

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem with CORS. You need to [enable CORS](https://enable-cors.org/)  on domain `fonts.gstatic.com`. Or use the same domain for static files as main site.

Comment: But, the issue is I am not pulling the material-icons from any outside site. I have installed it in node modules, and pulling the icons in index.js from the node modules folder.